# Notice: Use of undefined constant SCRIPT_DEBUG

Tags: errors

I'm getting this error at the top of my wordpress site:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant SCRIPT_DEBUG - assumed 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' in /[wordpress path]/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4144

No idea where it came from, any ideas what started causing this?

Using version 4.2.1

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using? 4.2.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32118?cversion=0&cnum_hist=10)

As far as I'm concerned, you can easily fix it by replacing

```
if ( SCRIPT_DEBUG ) {
```

with

```
if ( defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) {
```

That should suppress the error for now.

When Wordpress is updated again, this error may be overwritten, but I believe it will be fixed in the next update.

**UPDATE**

Fixed at build 32482.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't wish to modify your core wordpress files to fix the issue, you can simply add the missing definition into your `wp.config.php` file.

Something like: 

   `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`

Would remove the error.

There is already a `WP_DEBUG` definition in there already so I would suggest putting it close to that.